# Why can't I embed this site in an iframe?

Tags: iframe

When I put this code into HTML file, it does not show the website.

```
<iframe src="https://runepedia.com/calculators/combat">
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the site set [`X-Frame-Options` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to `DENY`.

This means that the browser cannot show the page in an iframe.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options):

> ## `deny`
>
> The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.